# Express session module not saving session cookie in cross site application

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express-session

I am running a node.js app on `http://localhost:3002` and a client side app on `http://localhost:5173` (hosted with vite tooling)

I am trying to send cookies from the server to the client to authenticate users using `express-session`, but every request that comes in keeps generating as a new session. The cookies are not sending properly.

Node.js code

```
    this.#app.use(cookieParser());

    this.#app.use(cors({
        origin: WEB_CLIENT_URL,
        credentials: true,
        methods:'GET, POST',
        allowedHeaders:'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization'
    }));
    
    var sess = {
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: false,
        cookie: {
            secret: 'yourSecret',
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
            sameSite: "none" as "none",
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 24 hours
            domain: undefined//'localhost:3002'
        },
    }
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        this.#app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
    }
    this.#app.use(session(sess));

    this.#app.use(async (req, res, next)=> {

        // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin ?? "");

        // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
        // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
        // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        const session = req.session as Session;
        console.log(req.session.id, req.method, req.originalUrl);
        if (!session.user) {
            const access = await TokenCollection.CreateAccessToken();
            session.user = access.token;
            req.session.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    next(Utils.GetError('Error creating session', 500));
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }); 
        } else {
            console.log("FOUND USER");
            next();
        } 
    });
```

and client side

```
response = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/api/user", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(profile_form_data),
    headers: {
        'authorization': `Bearer ${access.token}`,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include'
});
```

BTW im running in dev mode so `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` will be false.

Does anyone know what's wrong?